# Server-side MediaWiki interface for integration with Yii project

Tags: yii, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I need to integrate MediaWiki in my Yii project.
Is MediaWiki-API URL-based only? 
Yii and MW on same server. I want to manipulate with php-commands, not cUrl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to call the API internally, though it requires some understanding of MediaWiki's inner workings. I suggest you start reading at [API:Calling internally](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aCalling_internally)

Comment: Hmm. Do I need to include something before using "$params = new DerivativeRequest..."? Something like WebRequest.php

Comment: `DerivativeRequest` is used inside an existing user request context. Otherwise use [`FauxRequest`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classFauxRequest.html) (see the bottom of the linked page).

Without any idea about what exactly you are trying to do, it's hard to be more precise.

Comment: I have folder "wiki" on server, with MediaWiki files. And I have other folder "protected" with my site files. I need create test.php file in folder "protected", wich do something with MediaWiki content via API. For example - show main page text.

Comment: Found AutoLoader class. Is there any php-example of using AutoLoader and FauxRequest Classes?

Comment: Many MediaWiki extensions does this, but if you want to do it entirely outside MediaWiki, loading all necessery classes, I havn't seen any. Sound like using the API would be a much, much simpler, and more stable way in that case...

Comment: Yep, I want to do it entirely outside MediaWiki, on the same server, including all necessary files. So, your advice, to use MW-API on the same server sending cUrl-queries?

Comment: I don't know your needs and situation, but yes, making a request to the MediaWiki API (with curl or something else) would be the normal approach, with the benefit of keeping you applications separate, and thus more maintainable.

Comment: I need to integrate Wiki in my site design. Based on MediaWiki. There will be tab "Wiki". And I want to get/set Wiki-texts from MW-db, with php.

Comment: Ok, so basically you have two sites: One MediaWiki wiki and another site, from where some things in the same wiki can also be edited? That sounds like a perfect job for the MediaWiki API! There are also some [frameworks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#PHP) that can help you accessing the API.